# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() get hardware Storage

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm trying to get all files list from SD card by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() but i get back list from hardware Storage. I tried hardcoded but result is that same. Any idea what could be causing this?

My code

```
  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/";
     Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
     File f = new File(path);        
     File file[] = f.listFiles();
     Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
     for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
     {
         Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
     }
```

Return

```
Path: /mnt/sdcard/
 Size: 21
FileName:LOST.DIR
 FileName:.android_secure
 FileName:Music
 FileName:Podcasts
```

But i dont`t have Podcasts etc. in SDcard.

Half answer: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() get inside memory storage in some case. If i try  String path = "/mnt/external_sd/"; then its work. But in other devices storage is in other dir.

Comment: Just wondering, are you sure there are no hidden files by the names of 'Podcasts' etc?

Comment: Look at my edit "Half-Answer", in my device "/sdcard/" is not sdcard, this is hardware storage. I must use "/mnt/external_sd/" but this work only in my case. I am trying to find some solution that will work in all device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/Save PIP/");
            dir.mkdirs();


            File file = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");


           // Utils.showAlert("Image Saved to SD Card", "PIP Effect", "Ok", FrameActivity.this);

            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            try {

                output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap_final.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I wish that it will help you.